# Nested User Controls in top level Scroll Viewer not resulting in a scroll bar

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a main window with a scroll viewer that houses and items control with a user control:

```
   <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding oObsByDiv}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <uc:ucObservationsHeader/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

ucObservationsHeader shows a title bar with a nested list of observations in another user control.  This runs off the page, and I have a scroll bar visible, but it does not allow any scrolling.  I think the scroll viewer just sees the top level user control as not needing any scrolling, even though the nested content is scrolling way below the screen.  How do I get this to work?

Here are the ucObservationsHeader and ucObservations xaml:
ObservationHeader:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucObsevationsHeader"
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="300*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBox x:Name="divNum" Text="{Binding DivNum, Mode=OneWay}" 
    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
<TextBox x:Name="divName" Text="{Binding DivName, Mode=OneWay}" 
    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding lObs}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <uc:ucObservationsView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid></UserControl>
```

Observations:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucObservationsView">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtDivObs" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding obsFullNum, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblOpenDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Open " Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="dtOpen" HorizontalAlignment="Right" SelectedDate="{Binding Opendate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblCLoseDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Close " Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="txtCloseDate" HorizontalAlignment="Right" SelectedDate="{Binding Closedate}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtImagePath" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ImagePath}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding 
                   DataContext.PreviewImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'm doing this to show a layout with division headers for the Observations, and have structured my data accordingly.  Without the scrollbar working this is useless though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my MainWindow I have 4 rows defined:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="25"/>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
<RowDefinition Height="50"/>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The 4th row is where my user control inside the scroll viewer resides.  The Auto is what causes my problem, setting that to "200*" fixed the problem and the scroll bar appears as expected.  I'm not sure why I set that to Auto in the first place but in case anyone has this similar situation this is something to look out for.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this may be related to your spelling mistake in ucObservationsHeader, although that should normally throw up a compile error:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucObsevationsHeader"
```

Other than that I couldn't reproduce it, which suggests to me that it might be a theming issue. I think you're going to have to provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will put together an mcve (with a not insignificant chance that the process will yield the solution).  The typo you point out is just from me taking out the class name etc. from the user control header for better readability.